# ListView and PullToRefresh swipe down conflict

Tags: android, listview, android-actionbar, swipe, pull-to-refresh

I have used @chrisbanes `ActionBar-PullToRefresh` with my project, now I'm facing a conflict between `ListView` and `PullToRefresh` swipe down gesture.
When the `ListView` is already scrolled and I want to get to the top by swiping down, `PullToRefresh` trigger a refresh action instead of swiping the list up.

PS :
Here is my source code without extra stuff.

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment implements OnRefreshListener {
    private PullToRefreshLayout mPullToRefreshLayout;
    private TestAdapter testAdapter;
    private ListView testListView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.testActivity = (TestActivity)getActivity();
        PullToRefreshLayout testLayout = (PullToRefreshLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_list_view, null);
        this.testData = new ArrayList<Object>();

        // Set List Adapter
        this.testListView = new ListView(this.testActivity);
        this.testData = getSearchResult();
        this.testAdapter = new TestAdapter(this.testActivity, this.testData);
        testListView.setAdapter(this.testAdapter);
        testListView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

        testLayout.addView(twitterListView);

        return testLayout;
    }

    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;
        // As we're using a Fragment we create a PullToRefreshLayout manually
        mPullToRefreshLayout = new PullToRefreshLayout(viewGroup.getContext());

        // We can now setup the PullToRefreshLayout
        ActionBarPullToRefresh.from(getActivity())
                // We need to insert the PullToRefreshLayout into the Fragment's ViewGroup
                .insertLayoutInto(viewGroup)
                // all children are pullable
                .allChildrenArePullable()
                .listener(this)
                .setup(mPullToRefreshLayout);
    }

        @Override
    public void onRefreshStarted(View view) {
        final TestAdapter adapter = this.testAdapter;
        final TestActivity activity = this.testActivity;
        final PullToRefreshLayout pull2Refresh = this.mPullToRefreshLayout;

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                /// refresh data source
                getFragmentData(activity, true);
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // Notify Program Adapter that data has changed
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
                // Notify PullToRefreshLayout that the refresh has finished
                pull2Refresh.setRefreshComplete();
            }
        }.execute();

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any other touch listener on your list view?  Can we see the code to hook up the PullToRefreshAttacher?

Comment: No I don't have any other touch listener. and i'm using a PullToRefreshLayout and attaching ActionBarPullToRefresh to it in the onViewCreated

Comment: https://github.com/jenuprasad/swipe-pullltorefresh-listview

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue
It was my mistake, first i must load `ListView` from `Layout` by identifier

```
-- this.testListView = new ListView(this.testActivity);
++ this.testListView = (ListView)testLayout.findViewById(R.id.test_listview);
```

And remove the last line

```
-- testLayout.addView(twitterListView);
```